# Why is array.push() not working correctly?

Tags: node.js, angular, ionic-framework

I have a function which returns an array of dishes from a firestore database. 
With console.log I check that the dish I want to push is correctly formatted, then push it.

Finally I console.log the array to check if everything is alright.
Here is what I got:

https://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2019/05/5/1549048418-arraypush.png

```
switch (type) {
  case "Plats": {
    this.nourritureCollection.ref.get().then(data => {

      let platArray : Plat[] = [];
      data.docs.forEach(doc => {
        this.plat.name = doc.data().nourritureJson.name;
        this.plat.price = doc.data().nourritureJson.price;
        this.plat.ingredients = doc.data().nourritureJson.ingredients;
        this.plat.type = doc.data().nourritureJson.type;
        this.plat.availableQuantity = doc.data().nourritureJson.availableQuantity;
        this.plat.isAvailableOffMenu = doc.data().nourritureJson.isAvailableOffMenu;
        this.plat.imgUrl = doc.data().nourritureJson.imgUrl;
        this.plat.temp = doc.data().nourritureJson.temp;
        console.log(this.plat)
        platArray.push(this.plat);
      });

      console.log(platArray)
      return platArray;
    });
    break;
  }...
```

plat is instantiated within my service component, I couldn't declare a new `Plat()` inside my function.

The expected result is that dishes should be different in my array of dishes.

Comment: You push the same object each time.

Comment: you are constantly changing only the one object `this.plat`. Use `let plat` in forEach instead :)

Comment: Yeah i don't know why it behave like this though. I though it would replace the old properties with the new ones. I tried to create a new object before but couldn't strangely due to some blocked scope :/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are updating `this.plat` in every iteration. So it will have `n` number of references in the array pointing to the same object, therefore, the values for all the array elements will be last updated value of `this.plat`

What you need is to create `new` `Plat` object for every iteration.

```
data.docs.forEach(doc => {
        let plat: Plat = new Plat();
        plat.name = doc.data().nourritureJson.name;
        plat.price = doc.data().nourritureJson.price;
        plat.ingredients = doc.data().nourritureJson.ingredients;
        plat.type = doc.data().nourritureJson.type;
        plat.availableQuantity = doc.data().nourritureJson.availableQuantity;
        plat.isAvailableOffMenu = doc.data().nourritureJson.isAvailableOffMenu;
        plat.imgUrl = doc.data().nourritureJson.imgUrl;
        plat.temp = doc.data().nourritureJson.temp;
        console.log(plat)
        platArray.push(plat);
      });
```

As pointed out in the comment, you can only use `new Plat()` if `Plat` is a `class`, if it is an `interface`, just `let plat:Plat;` would do.

Comment: Do we know that Plat is a class or interface?

Comment: Well, now actually when looking at the image linked, `plat` is indeed a class :P But yeah, it doesn't really show clearly in OP's question... so... I'm forgiven, right? :D  (and I didn't downvote)

Comment: Plat was a class, it worked (i tried before couldn't get it working cause of some blocked scope don't know why...).
Thanks anyway !